# libcurl error when running Boinc

Tags: boinc

I downloaded the latest versione of Boinc x64. When I run the manager, there is an error

```
./boincmgr: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you refering to the official BOINC package (which should also be at the latest version or very close to that) or to a download from boinc.berkeley.edu?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to install the Ubuntu package `libcurl3` to provide the shared object file (=library) that the command complains about missing. Install it either through the Software Center or by writing `sudo apt-get install libcurl3` in a terminal window (it will ask for your password to be able to install the program onto the system).

Is there any particular reason that you have not installed the `boinc` package that comes with Ubuntu, by the way? If it were me, I would prefer to have updates coming in for a program that turns my computer into a work node that executes code that I can't really verify for myself. :-)

Comment: Right. There is the client application that controls the computation (the one Jorge presumably downloaded as a binary from Berkeley) and there are executables typically downloaded from various project servers that perform the (usually) scientific computations. To avoid executing black boxes (and hopefully attracting more people to these good causes) Debian+Ubuntu provide packages for the client app and selected scientific apps like shipping with boinc-app-seti.

Answer (score -2):

https://launchpad.net/~xapienz/+archive/ubuntu/curl34
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xapienz/curl34
sudo apt-get update

Comment: How does this solve OP's issue?  They probably just don't have Curl or its libs installed and doing that would not need a PPA.